# Bounding box for printing map for publication from ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, printing, layouts

I have created a vector map in ArcMap 10.6 and this will be printed by a publisher we are working with.  I have been given dimensions (610 x 812 mm) for a bounding box which will be the visible part of the map that is included in the publication.  I need to add this bounding box to the map which I will export in TIFF format, and it has to have some 'bleed' outside the box for the printer.

Is there a tool for creating this rectangle?

It is important the dimensions are completely accurate (and that I can move the box easily if people think it needs to move slightly to the left or right after I show them my first draft).  I had thought of creating a rectangle in ArcMap data view but I would have thought there was some tool in layout view that might work better.

Comment: You say that you "have been given dimensions for a bounding box which will be the visible part of the map that is included in the publication".  What are those dimensions?  I think knowing their units will be important for any potential answerer.

Comment: I have been asked if I can ensure the size is exactly 610 x 812 mm - thanks.

Comment: When you say "the visible part of the map" do you mean the visible part of the Data Frame or the visible part of the Layout (page)?

Comment: I mean the part that is visible in the final printed map that the printer will send back to us - but I have to send him a map with a 'bleed' so that means that what is in my Layout will have include more information (i.e. a small amount of map that is outside the margins of the bounded box).  Bounded box is what they have been referring to it as, but perhaps I should be using another term. Essentially it will provide the corners for cropping.

Answer (score 1):

Use Data Frame Properties window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the term that you may be looking for is a neatline.

To make these is ArcMap you can use a Graphic Rectangle - see [Working with graphic elements, neatlines, pictures, and objects](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/working-with-graphic-elements-pictures-and-neatlin.htm#GUID-FCC30A69-ECF2-415C-A859-C79ADE91A51B) where it says:

> You can use graphic rectangles (neatlines) to frame a group of other
>   map elements. If you want to frame an individual map element,
>   right-click it, click Properties, then click the Frame tab. You can
>   use this method to choose borders and backgrounds for legends, north
>   arrows, data frames, scale bars, and scale text.

On the Main Menu under Insert you will find Neatline that you may or may not find useful for creating a Graphic Rectangle:

[image]

Once you have a neatline you may then want to look at [Moving, rotating, and ordering graphics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/moving-rotating-and-ordering-graphics.htm):

> Much of the work you do while building your map involves arranging
>   graphics and other elements. For instance, you might want to orient
>   graphics or position map elements, such as titles, neatlines, and
>   north arrows, on the layout.
>
> ArcMap provides a number of tools that let you position and orient
>   graphics. You can move graphics by dragging them with the mouse
>   pointer or, when you need more precise control, you can nudge them up,
>   down, left, or right. You can also position graphics at a specified
>   coordinate location. You can order graphics by moving one graphic on
>   top of another one, rotating it, and flipping it horizontally or
>   vertically.

Answer (score -1):

In the end I found that the easiest thing was to go into the drawing toolbar in layout view and just insert a rectangle.  It allowed me to insert the precise dimensions as specified by the printer, and the full layout means there is a bleed beyond the rectangle.

Comment: I believe that is just another path to [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/310944/115) because my understanding is that Insert | Neatline just inserts a Rectangle graphic.